# Setters: Consumer vs. direct method call

Tags: rx-java2

Why would you use a [Consumer](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/Consumer.html)

```
public Consumer<String> setValue();
```

instead of direct function call

```
public void setValue(String value);
```

for setters?

I only see disadvantages:

- the direct method call is more readable
- another disadvantage of the `Consumer` variant is, that the calling code must always handle exceptions explicitly

  ```
  try {
      instance.setValue().accept("newValue");
  } catch (Exception e) {
      // handle exception
  }
  ```

Comment: what's the context? where  do you need to use it?

Comment: @yosriz: that is exactly my question. I'm just getting started with RxJava and I have seen this somewhere - maybe in a blog post or example-app. Unfortunately I cannot find this source anymore: Thus the question, if this can have advantages: e.g. maybe it's easier to combine in an rx-flow, ..

Answer (score 1):

`Consumer` is an interface intended mostly for internal use within RxJava. Since you are getting started with RxJava, you shouldn't worry about it.

The whole purpose of RxJava is to flow data, the more you use it the less you handle state or use setters.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `Consumer`, when you cannot use method references for some reason: e.g. when you target older Android versions, that don't support Java8.
Note: with the [new Android toolchain](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html), Java8 method references are supported directly (even without [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda), etc.), so this is not required anymore.

Thanks to Jake Wharton who answered in [rx-preferences #96](https://github.com/f2prateek/rx-preferences/issues/96)